# Create a simple web services on Ubuntu

Tags: web-services

I'm a newbie in web services. How can I develop a simple one on my Ubuntu box?
Is there any packages I need to install first?

Comment: It'd be easier to answer if you asked how to develop a particular service.  Maybe you just want to enable httpd and serve up error messages?

Comment: I would like to send some parameters using the HTTP, and want the web service to respond in XML. Any simple example that I can follow?

Answer (score 3):

Well since you didn't say what language or even what webservices try this:

> ```
> sudo apt-get install apache2
> sudo apt-get install php5
> sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
> ```

Goto /var/www/ create a file called hello.php

```
<?php
    echo "<webservice><hello>world</hello></webservice>";
?>
```

Goto http://localhost/hello.php and you already have a webservice returning some XML. That's how they all work (no matter what language you choose, ASP.NET is just better in hiding that).

Comment: Thanks dude. But how about is I want to use javascript? Is it the same packages and steps?

Comment: My input to the web service would be something like this: http://localhost/index.html?id=test&hosts=test&lang=en-US&version=test&auth=test

Comment: I don't know what you want to do with JavaScript. It is mainly a client side language, not for server side webservices (though there is a JavaScript server called Jaxer http://www.jaxer.org/). To be honset it seems to me that you should make yourself generally more familiar with web technologies, so that you can ask a more specific question.

Comment: For example, if I want my web service to process my HTTP parameters, means that I need to program the logics inside the PHP file ?

Comment: Yes. Your example can be processed by e.g. accessing $_GET['hosts'] which has the hosts= parameter from your http request in the PHP script.